# Best datatype for multiple IDs in one field?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm designing my database structure. I need to save multiple IDs like this:

```
8694564795903436667,18280427823078344486,15033597879242900284,17492244717654560088
```

What would be the best datatype for this? I need to index it too.

Comment: If you're saving multiple anything in a single field, you need to rethink your table design.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure your number can't get bigger than `18446744073709551615`, then you can use the [UNSIGNED BIGINT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/integer-types.html) data type.

Otherwise use a `varchar` data type.

#### And always store single values. Never store multiple values in one column!

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted. If those numbers to store can be bitmapped, remain semantically valid, and be recovered in a single field, a UNSIGNED BIGINT seems reasonable to me.

Comment: Perhaps because the poster is asking how to store multiple IDs in one field and choosing BIGINT only allows one number to be stored, not multiple.  While I do not agree with the original posters design decision, this answer doesn't provide a valid answer to the posters request.

Comment: @SlyRaskal: Stzring multiple values in a column is just **no option**. That is why I did not suggest a way to do that.

Comment: But telling the person to use BIGINT as an answer to *his* question is inaccurate. Do you understand that?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the data you specified that you wish to store, you have no choice but to use a varchar or text datatype. HOWEVER, I highly encourage you to rethink your database design because storing multiple IDs in one field is a very poor design.

**Use the strength of what a database is built for, storing data in a cell that can be mapped to other records/tables with proper use of relationships.**